# Matlab - Getting submatrix

Tags: matlab

Okay, I use the following code to shuffle the rows of a `MxN` matrix called `data`:

```
newData = data(randperm(size(data, 1)), :);
```

So far so good, what I need now is to keep the first `K` rows. Of course I can do this:

```
newData = data(randperm(size(data, 1)), :);
newData = newData(1:K, :);
```

But I am trying to do this (just out of curiosity) in just one line. What I tried is this:

```
newData = data(randperm(size(data, 1)), :)(1:K, :);
```

Well, it obviously failed. I know it's not important and probably a stupid question but does anyone know a way to do this in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're randomly permuting your matrix, then taking the top `K` rows. Instead, just select `K` random rows:

```
newData = data(randperm(size(data, 1), K), :);
```

The second argument to `randperm` says to choose `K` values from `1:size(data, 1)`.

Comment: Easier than I thought. Thank you !!

Comment: Doing it this way also has the advantage that there is no intermediate variable, so you save on memory.